# Where are my files?

Tags: sql-server, alter-database

The DBA run a file relocation script to move the physical Database file from where it was running to I:.

```
ALTER DATABASE [cro01] MODIFY FILE ( name=cro01,filename=N'i:\SQLData\cro01.MDF')
```

He take the Database offline ad copy the file. 
But *for some strange reason* he don't finnish the job correctly. We have now mdf files duplicated and we dont know which one is running. How do I know the "real" running location of the files via a Tsql query? Is it posible? I want to avoid checking manually each disk file location against each sys.master_files entry.

Answer (score 3):

[dbatools](https://dbatools.io/download/) to the rescue - use [`Find-DbaOrphanedFile`](https://docs.dbatools.io/#Find-DbaOrphanedFile)

> This command searches all directories associated with SQL database files for database files that are not currently in use by the SQL Server instance.
>
> By default, it looks for orphaned .mdf, .ldf and .ndf files in the root\data directory, the default data path, the default log path, the system paths and any directory in use by any attached directory.
>
> You can specify additional filetypes using the -FileType parameter, and additional paths to search using the -Path parameter.

e.g. Below command will - Connect to sqlserver2014a, authenticating with SQL Server authentication, and searches for orphaned files. Returns server name, local filename, and unc path to file.

```
$cred = get-credential -UserName yourUserThatHasAccessToYourServer -Message "Enter correct Password"
#above will pop up message box to enter the password !
Find-DbaOrphanedFile -SqlInstance sqlserver2014a -SqlCredential $cred
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to find the real physical name

```
exec sp_helpdb <your db name>

-- or
select * from master.sys.master_files
where database_id = db_id('<your db name>')
```

Comment: Sorry, this query tell me where it should be, not where it really is. Pf I run the above alter and change the path where the files are running now to a new location, the Database continue to point to the "old" place while the script tell you where it should be. When you take the DB offline and online again, then the DB start using the new path and forget the old location. Of course, you need to copy or move the files to the new location also.

Comment: after you alter the database to point its path to a new location, this `alter` action only changes the metadata info. But I kind of understand you now, what you want to know is where is the real data file location the sql server engine uses after I `alter` the file location but BEFORE setting the db offline and online again. This is indeed an interesting question.

Comment: Right jyao!! You got it. It seems difficult to get the info with a single query on the SQL: